# Java doc patterns

Tags: java, javadoc

I refactored a class by moving some of the methods to different class. Since this was like an Architecture refactoring and not code refactoring, I was wondering if it is a good practice to mention in the javadoc of the new classes that it contains the methods moved from previously existing X class?. For example

/**
Processor that sets sequence to the payment group. This processor has been added as part of checkout refactor project and xxxMethod() method has been moved from {@link XXXFormHandler} to this pipeline processor.
**/

I like this approach since it gives clear picture to any developer involved in maintaining this code. My only concern is if this is exposed as an API, then those information will be shown to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think that this is useful. You had strong reasons to refactor the code so developers knowing the new code only should not bother with the old architecture. Developers knowing the old code only don’t know where in the new code they have to look for that javadoc and once they know, they don’t need it anymore. So they need a migration guide which exists independently of the javadoc.

Regarding the last concern, if API users shall not see the particular documentation, regular comments do the right thing as maintainer seeing the source code see the comments.